# Add jQuery Mobile transition to ASP.Net MVC Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

How does one add a jQuery Mobile transition to an HTML POST rendered with the ASP.Net MVC `Html.BeginForm` helper?

The transition requires an HTML attribute `data-transition` be added (I think to the `form` tag, but the docs are unclear on that point, providing only [a hyperlink example](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-transitions.html)).

I'm trying to use the `BeginForm` overload to add attributes to the rendered `form` tag.  When using the `new { ... }` syntax to declare an anonymous class representing the HTML attributes, I get an error if an attribute name has a dash in it.

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, 
    new {  data-transition="pop" }))
```

Error: *Invalid anonymous type member declarator*

This, in spite of the fact that the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492714.aspx) shows an attribute with a dash in the name

```
new { id = "text1", accept-charset="iso-8859-1" }
```

Comment: By the way, *declarator* is a real word http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/declarator.  Just not in the sense Microsoft is using it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dictionary:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, 
    new Dictionary<string, object>{{ "data-transition", "pop" }} ))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use an anonymous object to specify your attributes then you could do the following

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { data_transition = "pop" } ))
```

In short you replace the hypen with an underscore