# Jquery Mobile Transitions in MVC4 with Form Post

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm fairly new to jQuery mobile so forgive any oversights.

I'm creating a mobile app that has a series of pages with information and forms on. In the simplest case the first page has one text box to record a location which is then submitted via form post to a controller. When the controller saves this information it then redirects to another action.

```
    using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Controller"))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary("Please correct the errors below")

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            @Html.LabelFor(l => l.Location)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Location, new { placeholder = "Type Current Location" })
        </div>

        <input type="submit" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="right" value="Begin" />
    }
```

Once the post has been submitted the controller performs the action and then returns this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Search");
```

As this is being done through a form and a post back it simply loads the new page rather than using a jQuery transition.

What i'd like to do is to use a transition when it goes from the start page to the search page.

I've looked at various other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283305/add-jquery-mobile-transition-to-asp-net-mvc-form) which have suggested adding information into the route values of the form to append the `data-transition` tag such as:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new Dictionary<string, object>{{ "data-transition", "pop" }} ))
```

or such as

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { data_transition = "pop" } ))
```

But this didn't work for me.

From other google searches and the like it sounds like this should be possible but wondered if due to the way I post and then redirect from the controller it will not work.

I then thought that due to the way transitions work, by loading the next page into the DOM such that it can then be animated to that I would have to do this via Ajax. So instead. use a `@Html.BeginForm` Helper but then attach onto it using jQuery such that the form does a `$.Post` instead. At which point I attempted to return a JavascriptResult like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538523/how-to-get-an-asp-net-mvc-ajax-response-to-redirect-to-new-page-instead-of-inser) However the browser either attempted to download a script file or it just loaded the text sent back in the page and nothing else.

However when I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148632/redirecting-to-another-page-in-asp-net-mvc-using-javascript-jquery) Darin's answer states that if all i want is to redirect the page, then Ajax doesn't really need to be used. Which I agree with so it seemed like I was going in the wrong direction.

Can someone please clarify if what i'm attempting to do is possible with Posting and MVC with jQuery mobile, or if i will have to do some heavy code modifications to re-work my page flow so that transitions can be used?